# How to return a json array from WCF rest service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote a function with return type `String`

```
public String LoginGet(string Username, string Password)
{
 returnValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FinalDatatable);
}
```

program ran successfully.

But problem is its not create a pure json array.
Result is come like that,

```
"[{\"TestCode\":\"1\",\"Time\":\"120\",\"StudentCode\":\"1\",\"ClassName\":\"11th\",\"Name\":\"Akshay B C\"}]"
```

extra `""` and `\` is added to the result.

how to create

```
[{"TestCode":"1","Time":"120","StudentCode":"1","ClassName":"11th","Name":"Akshay B C"}]"
```

Result here is without additional `"` and `\` characters.

Comment: How are you viewing this value? I'm willing to bet it is returning the right thing, but your client is escaping the string. (VS's IDE will do this.)

Comment: This question has been asked hundreds of times in SO. The two strings are identical. The first string comes from the debugger's watch window and escapes special characters. `\"` is exacly how you would add `"` in a C# string

Comment: Yes i know this two string are identical

Comment: But when i write a get method and look into the browser string is come with \"

Comment: and when andriod person try to access the string he is get the response like "Not a valid JSON format"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with this code

```
          string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ResultSymbol);
          return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
```